# Trying to locate SafeMM for Delphi

Tags: delphi, debugging, memory-management

Mark Edington mentioned a Memory Manager called, SafeMM at the DelphiLive conference.

I have been unable to locate it online, does anyone know where it might be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a more recent version (v0.4) with source from Embarcadero's Code Central: http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27241

Comment: That's still only for Delphi version 7.

Answer (score 6):

From my notes, it's an internal tool.
You won't find in the open.
But Mark nicely included it in his [DelphiLive materials](http://it-republik.de/konferenzen/delphi_live/material/delphilive09_eddington_advanced_debugging_techniques_for_delphi.zip)...

Answer (score 2):

Mark Eddington talked about SafeMM at Delphi Live and apparently included in his conference materials.  If you can't find them, you might contact Mark directly.

Comment: This worked as well.  But Francois had the link to the materials.

Comment: His answer is definitely more complete.  I couldn't find the link.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [SafeMM demo here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/javascript/play.html?u=y&w=1024&h=768&s=18.4MB&f=http%3a%2f%2fcc.embarcadero.com%2fdownload.aspx%3fid%3d27285%26file%3dMarkEdington_Debugging.swf&d=http%3a%2f%2fcc.embarcadero.com%2fdownload.aspx%3fid%3d27285). Go to the 23 minute of the screencast for a demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick Googling of SafeMM and couldn't find it either.  We use FastMM here for memory management stuff and it works really well.  You can download it here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/

Hope that helps!

Comment: We use FastMM already. 

Based on the presentation SafeMM is used for debugging purposes it's slower, but will catch Errors that FastMM is not designed to catch.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't comment on the answer (not enough reputation :-(), but I just wanted to say that someone (perhaps Mr. Eddington himself?) should post the source on Code Central for everyone's benefit.

Answer (score 0):

http://twitter.com/jdmullin/status/1964322021

This guy mentioned he found SafeMM in the material from Mark Edington from the Delphi Live conference.